# Probability of a sequence of intervals

Tags: probability-theory

Let $E_n = \{2+\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 3\}$ and define $C = [1, 4]$ with $P([a, b]) = \frac{(b-a)}{3}$ for $1 \leq a \leq b \leq 4$. Find $P(\bigcup_{n} E_n)$.

To do this problem, have that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} E_n = (2, 3]$. Then, since $[1, 4]$ is an uncountable interval of point, $P[a, b] = P(a, b) = P[a, b) = P(a, b]$. So $P$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} E_n = P(2, 3]=\frac{3-2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$.

First, I am not sure if I have the union correctly. Second, I am unsure if my logic of saying $P[a, b] = P(a, b]$ is correct. Any help appreciated :).

Comment: I don't think that logic is fully correct. You should use properties of the probability measure to deduce it.

Comment: can you explain a bit what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

First, show that $\bigcup_nE_n = (2,3]$.
This should follow simply from definitions: show that every $x \in \bigcup_nE_n$ is also in $(2,3]$, and vice versa.

Now, let $0<\epsilon< b-a$ so that for all $n\in\Bbb N$ we have

$$\left[a+\frac\epsilon n, b\right] \subset (a,b] \subset [a,b],$$

which implies that for all $n\in\Bbb N$ we have

$$\Bbb P\left(\left[a+\frac\epsilon n, b\right]\right) \leqslant
\Bbb P\big((a,b]\big) \leqslant
\Bbb P\big([a,b]\big).\tag{1}$$

Use our given formula in expression $(1)$ and let $n\to \infty$ to conclude what $\Bbb P\big((a,b]\big)$ is.

Comment: Thanks! I am just confused, I don't understand why I can't say something like $P([a, b]) = P((a, b])$ since $P(x) =0$ if we are picking points from an uncountable set.

Comment: If you know it *a priori* for this particular measure (which is indeed a very well known/studied one), that's fine. It's not true though that for every probability measure on an uncountable set, atomic sets have probability $0$.

Answer (score 0):

From $$P([a, b]) = \frac{(b-a)}{3}$$ on $C = [1, 4]$ it is evident the distribution is uniform.

Thus$$ P(\bigcup_{n} E_n = P((2,3])=1/3$$